# Opening OpenStreetMap *.obf or *.pbf files in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap

*.obf and *.pbf are compressed binary file extensions of OSM data.

I want to open these in GIS software like ArcGIS.

How is the conversion possible?

Is there any automated tool?

Answer (score 1):

1. A GDAL/OGR driver on [reading PBF](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_osm.html) is currently under development.  Active testing is [underway](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-New-OGR-driver-to-read-OpenStreetMap-osm-pbf-files-td4987382.html).  You can use this driver to convert OSM's PBF file to any other vector data supported by GDAL/OGR.
2. Not entirely a PBF solution, but the original OSM format (*.osm) can be opened by ArcGIS's [OSM Editor](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/openstreetmap).

Answer (score 1):

SpatiaLite now supports opening ProtoBuf encoded OSM files (via the new [readosm](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/readosm/index) library). You can use that to import the files into SpatiaLite [tools](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite-tools/index) and then you can use tools like QGIS to do any work required. See the [documentation for SpatiaLite OSM tools](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite-tools/wiki?name=OSM%20tools) for specific details on the import and which tools to use for what purpose.

Comment: can you please specify how to work with spatiallite tools.

Comment: I provided a link to the documentation for these tools. Note that there are examples for each tool (e.g. see https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite-tools/wiki?name=spatialite_osm_map). I don't know which tools you need, because you didn't tell us why you wanted to open the files (i.e. what you are really trying to achieve).

Comment: I want to check the obf file for errors. I want to check the file in QGIS, so need to convert it into GIS format.

Comment: So just load it as a spatialite database in QGIS. The process is described in the link that I already provided: https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite-tools/wiki?name=spatialite_osm_map

Answer (score 0):

I tried using GDAL, but this is difficult for non-programmers.

This option is way more efficient and easy:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert

You can convert the file to an .osm, which can be opened through the ArcGIS for OSM tool. You get a large file though (file size x 20).